# I am trying to use 'connect-msonline' cmd on azure function with username and password but having proxy error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Am new to azure Active directory, my requirement is to connect to azure aad and to reset user MFA using an azure function. It should be done in a non interactive method. So am currently using username and password of a global administrator.

```
#powershell code
Import-module MSONline -UseWindowsPowershell

$username = $ENV:user
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $ENV:pword -asplaintext -force;
$cred = New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pwd
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud
```

Am having this error:

```
System.Exception,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolServiceException: Authentication Error: Unable to complete authentication request (potentially a proxy issue)
```

Comment: @siddheshdesaii The thread does not show any resolution to the problem

Comment: The MSOL module is pretty much deprecated now. Have you checked the Microsoft.Graph module? You can manage authentication methods through Graph at least: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hello @juunas thnks, I cannot find any graph command which can mimic the functionality: Require re-register MFA.

Comment: Are there any module in PS, i can use to perform the Require re-register MFA functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

To  **Require re-register MFA**  functionality, you can make use of below PowerShell command:

```
Connect-Msolservice

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName imran@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -StrongAuthenticationMethods @()
```

[image]

When the user will try to login,  **the register MFA screen will pop-up**  like below:

[image]

You can also  **Require re-register MFA**  through Azure Portal like below:

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Select your user -> Authentication Methods*

[image]

I agree with @*junnas*, MSOL module has been deprecated. But currently there is no Graph module to re-register MFA.

**Reference**:

[Microsoft Graph: Add support for “Require re-register MFA” - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/microsoft-graph-add-support-for-quot-require-re-register-mfa/idi-p/3062110)